# Laravel Sanctum: Access has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

[image]

I am using Nuxt.js, Laravel, and Laravel Sanctum for API development learning projects. Now, I have been stuck with this error for a few days. I know that Laravel Sanctum will handle everything on `config/cors.php` with some changes like I said at  [Nuxt.js - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099738/nuxt-js-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-re)

Then,

**Why I am facing this CORS error? Does anyone know something?**

**Please guide me, it will be helpful for me.**

Comment: Does this answer your questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429462/adding-access-control-allow-origin-header-response-in-laravel-5-3-passport ?

Comment: You need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers at the origin.

Comment: Not help, both are the same thing using middleware or cors.php

Comment: Set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`  headers in the code and see if that works.

Comment: Laravel already set `'allowed_origins' => ['*']` by default at cors.php, then why we need to set it again.

Comment: CORS need to be set on the origin api where you are pulling the information. `api.technojs.com`  You can read more about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: `api.technojs.com` is my Laravel API project, `alpha.technojs.com` is Nuxtjs frontend project. I know that CORS needs to be set on `api.technojs.com` but it's already set on `cors.php`. Then why it's not working.

Comment: @JSTECH were you able to solve it? I'm facing the same issue with my React app.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Sadly say NO but in my case, it's could be different issues. I think the Frontend JavaScript Framework needs a full Nodejs server to handle CORS in the backend. Due to the absence of Nodejs on my static server, it might be thrown an error.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help.... but I suffered the same issue not locally, not on test, but on my PROD deployment of a project. What solved it for me is CHOWN'ing the entire Laravel project to 'www-data' . When my user was the owner of the Laravel project  I kept getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." like you. After CHOWN'ing it to'www-data' it worked as usual.

I can't tell you why this is the case besides something with PHP being represented as the "www-data" user or something like that ( I'm not that smart ). But hope this helps!

EDIT: my project is React <-> Laravel, my Cors.php was configured correctly the entire time.